# How to update CreatedDate field using API in Enterprise edition? Always throws an error

Tags: api, audit-fields

**Error**

`[2018-07-29 09:31:20] local.DEBUG: SALESFORCE_EXCEPTION:RESPONSE_BODY:[{"message":"Unable to create/update fields: CreatedDate. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE","fields":["CreatedDate"]}]`

**Action**

I did update the Audit fields on the system admin account by clicking a checkbox, but to no avail unfortunately. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

The Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation permission allows you to populate the audit fields *only* upon the insertion of records through the API (including data loader applications). You cannot update the audit fields on existing records.

Comment: That's not entirely true because in my previous company I was able to update CreatedDate using my API and the adminstrator had enabled Audit fields too.

Comment: It's possible there is an additional feature that Salesforce can enable for you to allow this, but I don't know about it and I've never seen it documented.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to David's answer and highlighted by the third answer [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000svmMQAQ), see the full instructions in [this help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&type=1&mode=1) on how to enable audit fields, which makes the *Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation* permission visible

> Setup -> User Interface -> User Interface: Select the checkbox for Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions.
>
> After enabling these organization wide permissions, you'll need to grant the following profile permissions to your Users with **custom profiles** (see notes below for standard profiles):
>
> - Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation - Allow the User to set audit fields (like 'Created By' or 'Last Modified By') when you create a record via API importing tools like Data Loader.
> - Update Records with Inactive Owners - Allow the User to update record owner and sharing-based records with inactive owners.

Use Permission Sets to enable these two new permission for Standard Profiles, like System Administrator.