# Update CreatedDate field value of a list to be displayed in UI

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datetime

I am trying to update the value of a field inside of a list to be returned to the LWC component. I don't want the update to happen on the database, but just on the UI.

As datetime values are stored in GMT, I am converting it to the users local timezone value just to be displayed in the UI.

With the below code I am getting this error -
Field is not writeable - points to the CreatedDate field.

```
public with sharing class theController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Task> getAllRecords(String contactRecordId) {  
        TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
        DateTime yesterday = System.now() - 1;
        List<Task> allTasks = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate FROM Task Where contact = :contactRecordId AND CreatedDate >= :yesterday];
        for(Task theTask: allTasks) {
            Datetime createdDate = theTask.CreatedDate.AddSeconds(tz.getOffset(theTask.CreatedDate)/1000);
            theTask.CreatedDate = createdDate;
        }
        return allTasks;
    }
}
```

Please advise. Thank you all.

UPDATE as per identigral reference to the post with same issue

```
TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
    for(Task theTask: allTasks) {
                Datetime createdDate = theTask.CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm', tz);
                theTask.CreatedDate = createdDate;
            }
```

What could be wrong above , I get an error saying method does not exist or incorrect signature for the format method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update CreatedDate field using API in Enterprise edition? Always throws an error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227150/how-to-update-createddate-field-using-api-in-enterprise-edition-always-throws-a)

Comment: @identigral I am not trying to update the CreatedDate field in the database, it should stay as it is. I just want it converted to the local timezone of the user to display it in the UI. I want the values of that field inside the list to have the converted value.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319213/salesforce-displaying-time-custom-field-in-gmt-instead-of-users-timezone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce displaying Time custom field in GMT instead of User's timezone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319213/salesforce-displaying-time-custom-field-in-gmt-instead-of-users-timezone)

Comment: Your post is confusing because the subject line says you want to "update system Created Date."  Please [edit] your post subject to a more accurate description.

Comment: I am sorry I updated the title. Also the above post referenced by @identigral should work, I get an error on the format method. I have updated the post with my latest code.

Comment: What does your LWC code look like that calls this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a WrapperClass and create properties for the changes you want to make just for the UI. Something like

```
public class TaskWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Task task;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String createdDate;
}
```

and your method can be updated to use this wrapper class

```
public static List<TaskWrapper> getAllRecords(String contactRecordId) {  
    TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
    DateTime yesterday = System.now() - 1;

    List<TaskWrapper> tasks = new List<TaskWrapper>();
    
    List<Task> allTasks = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate FROM Task Where contact = :contactRecordId AND CreatedDate >= :yesterday];
    for(Task theTask: allTasks) {
        TaskWrapper tw = new TaskWrapper();
        tw.task = theTask;
        tw.createdDate = theTask.CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm', tz);
        tasks.add(tw);
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, this was exactly what I was looking for.